# I need some help to build a SQL select query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server database and I need to get different data from two different tables In a single query, tables names:

Table #1 name: `Barcode`

It contains the following columns:

- `Num` --> this column is a foreign key
- `Barcode` ---> this column is the primary key

Table #2 name: `MatCard`

It contains the following columns:

- `Num`  --> This column is the primary key
- `Name`
- `Price4` --> This column is for retail price
- `Price24` --> This column is for wholesale price

I am trying to use this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    MatCard.Name AS name, MatCard.Price4 AS price, 
    Barcode.Barcode AS code 
FROM 
    MatCard, Barcode 
WHERE
    MatCard.Num = Barcode.Num 
    AND Barcode.Barcode  = :code
```

This query is working well, but this query gets me only on retail price from "Price4 column".

How can I get wholesale price from the `Price4` column when I scan a barcode for a packet, and get retail price from `Price24` column" when I scan a barcode for piece?

Note: `Barcode` column for packet and piece it a same Barcode column in the `Barcode` table

Thanks

Comment: How do you know it's a packet or piece based on your database content? Please post some actual sample data that shows the contents of your tables.

Comment: @KenWhite I can know it's a packet or piece based from Barcode label because Barcode on packet is a different Barcode on piece so when scan Barcode for packet get me wholesale price and when scan Barcode for piece get me retail price

Comment: Yes, barcodes are different but how do you know that one is a packet and not a piece? You have a "type" column in one of the tables? Maybe the barcodes have a different format for pieces and packets (for example different length)? Or some other option?

Comment: How does your **query** know whether it's a piece or packet? Your SQL doesn't know which barcode means what; it only knows it has a column. How does your query (who only sees that column name) know whether it's a piece or a packet in order to know which price column to use? All it knows is it has a barcode; it doesn't know from that barcode what type of item it is that barcode means. You need a column that indicates what type it is that you can use to select a price column. Without it, you have to resort to hard-coding barcodes into your query, and that's not going to work out well for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the existing query does work, then I think you are simply asking for an extra (or different?) column in the select clause, like this:

```
SELECT
    MatCard.Name as name
  , MatCard.Price24 as wholesale_price  -- just include the column here
  , MatCard.Price4 as retail_price
  , Barcode.Barcode as code 
FROM Barcode
INNER JOIN MatCard ON MatCard.Num = Barcode.Num 
WHERE Barcode.Barcode = :code
```

But before leaving, please learn to use SQL Standard join syntax. Th trick to help you do this is: *STOP using commas between the table names*. If you do that then you are forced to include the explicit join.